# Merge tags [mongo-java] and [mongodb-java] (or delete them?)

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

Both tags refer to the mongodb java bindings. [mongo-java](/questions/tagged/mongo-java) (120 questions, 4 followers) should be made a synonym of [mongodb-java](/questions/tagged/mongodb-java) (250+ questions, 70+ followers).

Or, should they be deleted in favor to tagging questions with [java](/questions/tagged/java) and [mondobg](/questions/tagged/mondobg)?

Most mongodb-java questions are already tagged with both (in addition), while most mongo-java questions are only tagged mongodb and mongo-java.